# execute .bat file from android

Tags: android, batch-file, video-encoding

i am trying to execute the xxx.bat file for rename the file from my Android app
and hear is my code

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"eduapp"+File.separator+"lock1.bat");
```

eduapp is Directory and lock1.bat is my bat file and content of it

```
ren /sdcard/eduapp .{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
```

but when i run app it throes error like..

```
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/mnt/sdcard/eduapp/lock1.bat] Working Directory: null Environment: null
```

basically **i want to hide some folder from sdcard .**
is their any anther way to run .bat or hide folder from sdcard .

Comment: Android is Posix at its core, not Windows. You'll have to use `mv` instead of `ren`, and `.sh` instead of `.bat`. But even then, I'm not sure your scheme here will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because .bat is dos batch files, while android based on linux?..
It's 'mv', not 'ren'. It's not '.bat', it's '.sh' (but it doesn't matter, in fact). Also, you have to run /bin/sh and pass script file as parameter, or run 'mv' directly with parameters - you can't exec text file.
But i'm sure java have it's own functions to move files, there is no need for shell scripts.

Comment: move and rename are the same (well, technically it isn't always true, but mv can handle all lower level details itself)

Comment: ok thanks it work but now the problem is (i want to hide some folder from sdcard)  that the my file displayed in some file explore is any other way to hide it. basically i want to secure some videos so i try encryption but it consume big time to decryption. i use Cipher with AES is any faster Algorithm.

Comment: If file name leaded by '.', then file managers recommended to consider it as 'hidden'. However, it could (and in many cases - should) be ignored. Data encryption is completely beyound your initial question. If you need extra fast (and extra weak) method, try XOR - it isn't cryptographic at all, but it will make your files unreadable by standard players.