# Performing multiple executions on Runtime exec

Tags: java, android, runtime.exec

I'm trying to do this simple unix ls in Android:

```
cd /data
```

then

```
ls
```

It should return all the content of /data folder.

I've this coded:

```
try {
       String line;
       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "ls /data"});
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()) );
       while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
         Log.d("debugging", line);
       }
       in.close();
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

The problem I'm facing at the moment, is that I can't do more than a single command at once. For example, if I write `ls /data` its returning nothing. It seems that he doesn't like spaces.

Everything works if I just write a single word like "ls" which is returning the list of root directory:

```
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): acct
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): cache
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): config
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): crashtag
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): d
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): data
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): default.prop
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): dev
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): etc
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): fstab
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): init
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): init.clrdex.sh
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): init.goldfish.rc
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): init.hostapd.sh
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): init.rc
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): init.semc.rc
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): init.usbmode.sh
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): logo.rle
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): mnt
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): mr.log
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): proc
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): root
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): sbin
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): sdcard
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): sys
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): system
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): ueventd.goldfish.rc
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): ueventd.rc
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): ueventd.semc.rc
03-19 22:51:59.241: D/debugging(16274): vendor
```

I've tried as someone mentioned, to fill that array with multiple commands, but its returning nothing. Blank.

```
{"ls","ls"} //this should return twice ls result.
```

**Any ideas how can I "concatenate" a command in Android Runtime?**

Comment: Do you really need System.exec? Have you considered using `listFiles()` method from File (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: I would use a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()`.

Comment: I do, because it's not what I'm trying to do at the end. I want to call a system program, but if I can't handle doing two different commands at "once" I won't be able to run those programs

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán May be you can make `.sh` script file with your required commands and run that file using java. I think its same concept of `.bat` file in windows. [--->  execute .bat file from android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561729/execute-bat-file-from-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need root access in order to execute `ls /data` command so you should first get su shell and then execute commands, for example:

```
// run command with su rights and return output of that command(inside su
// shell)
// command = "ls /data"
public static void suOutputExecute(String command) {
    try {
        int BUFF_LEN = 1024;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "system/bin/sh" });
        DataOutputStream stdin = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
        // from here all commands are executed with su permissions
        stdin.writeBytes(command + "\n"); // \n executes the command
        InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFF_LEN];
        int read;
        String out = new String();
        // while((read=stdout.read(buffer))>0) won't work here
        while (true) {
            read = stdout.read(buffer);
            out += new String(buffer, 0, read);
            if (read < BUFF_LEN) {
                // we have read everything
                break;
            }
        }
        stdout.close();
        Log.e("ROOT", out);
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ROOT", "Error", e);
    }
}
```

You need rooted device. For emulator you will still have to install superuser.

For commands that don't require su following code should works(I'm not able to test it right now):

```
public static void shExecute(String[] commands) {
    Process shell = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        // Acquire sh
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Starting exec of sh");
        shell = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh");//su if needed
        out = new DataOutputStream(shell.getOutputStream());

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(shell.getInputStream()));

        // Executing commands without root rights
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Executing commands...");
        for (String command : commands) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Executing: " + command);
            out.writeBytes(command + "\n");
            out.flush();
        }

        out.writeBytes("exit\n");
        out.flush();
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, sb.toString());
        shell.waitFor();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ShellRoot#shExecute() finished with error", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
            if(in != null){
                in.close();
            }
            // shell.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // hopeless
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With this code can I "read" the output that commands generated?

Comment: Yes, at least with the first example, I'm not entirely sure about the second.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "ls /data"});
```

You should either use exec(String command) or break "ls /data" into two strings

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "ls", "/data"});
```

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "ls", "/data"});` is apparently returning no data.

Comment: Is it throwing an exception at all?

Comment: Nothing. `catch (Exception e) {
       Log.d("debugging","Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
      }` nothing printed.

Comment: If you enter an obviously bogus command instead of "ls" do you get any error? It should throw IOException if it cannot execute the command for any reason.

Comment: nope, I also though so. If I type "dsadasofpasnfas" its returning nothing aswell. Maybe because `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()) );` just listens to stdout and not maybe stderr? i'm not sure about that...

Comment: Wait, its throwing exception now. For instance, for "pwd" -> `ExceptionError running exec(). Command: [pwd] Working Directory: null Environment: null`

Comment: Seems like @Lecho is onto some subtle restrictions with Android in that you need a rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored this exec command for a java Runtime, Create a file object with the path you want to "cd" to and then input it as a third parameter for the exec method.

```
public Process exec(String command,
                String[] envp,
                File dir)
         throws IOException
```

Executes the specified string command in a separate process with the specified environment and working directory.

This is a convenience method. An invocation of the form exec(command, envp, dir) behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation exec(cmdarray, envp, dir), where cmdarray is an array of all the tokens in command.

More precisely, the command string is broken into tokens using a StringTokenizer created by the call new StringTokenizer(command) with no further modification of the character categories. The tokens produced by the tokenizer are then placed in the new string array cmdarray, in the same order.

```
Parameters:
    command - a specified system command.
    envp - array of strings, each element of which has environment variable settings in the format name=value, or null if the subprocess should inherit the environment of the current process.
    dir - the working directory of the subprocess, or null if the subprocess should inherit the working directory of the current process. 
Returns:
    A new Process object for managing the subprocess 
Throws:
    SecurityException - If a security manager exists and its checkExec method doesn't allow creation of the subprocess 
    IOException - If an I/O error occurs 
    NullPointerException - If command is null, or one of the elements of envp is null 
    IllegalArgumentException - If command is empty
```